# Node servidor acceso remoto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, servidor, localhost

Tengo una aplicación Web que funciona como cliente-servidor. Deseo lanzar el servidor para que pueda producirse un acceso remoto desde otro ordenador a través de Internet.
Con la configuración en "localhost" funciona, teniendo en el servidor:

```js
cfg.listen_port     = 8080
cfg.url_host_str    = '127.0.0.1:'+ cfg.listen_port.toString()
```

Y en el cliente:

```js
constructor()
    {
        const fname = `ServerInterface.constructor`
        this.server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
        this.request    = null 
        this.curr_command = 'none'
        this.curr_request_ident = 0

    }
```

Quiero que el servidor sea accesible desde cualquier ordenador. He probado con lo siguiente pero no funciona:

1. Determinar la dirección IP del ordenador desde el que va a ser lanzado. Se puede obtener la dirección IP pública del ordenador utilizando servicios en línea como "What Is My IP" o ejecutando comandos en la terminal como "ipconfig" en Windows o "ifconfig" en Linux y macOS.
2. Editar el servidor. Actualmente tiene `cfg.listen_port     = 8080`, se debe cambiar el valor del puerto asegurándose de elegir un puerto que no esté siendo utilizado por otros servicios en el ordenador y que sea accesible a cualquier ordenador en Internet
3. Actualizar el servidor donde se define la dirección del servidor para que escuche en todas las interfaces de red en lugar de solo en "localhost" o "127.0.0.1". Se puede hacer reemplazando la línea

   ```js
   cfg.url_host_str    = '127.0.0.1:'+ cfg.listen_port.toString()
   ```

   por

   ```js
   cfg.url_host_str    = '0.0.0.0:'+ cfg.listen_port.toString()
   ```

   Esto permitirá que el servidor escuche en todas las interfaces de red disponibles.
4. Guardar los cambios en el servidor
5. Abrir una ventana de terminal y navegar hasta la ubicación del archivo "servidor.js". Ejecutar el servidor Node.js escribiendo el comando `node servidor.js` en la terminal y presionando Enter. El servidor se iniciará y comenzará a escuchar las solicitudes en el puerto especificado.
6. Una vez que el servidor esté en funcionamiento, se podrá acceder a él desde otros ordenadores conectados a internet. Para ello, desde otro dispositivo, abre un navegador web y escribe la siguiente URL en la barra de direcciones:

   ```
   http://<dirección IP>:<puerto>
   ```

   Reemplazando `<dirección IP>` con la dirección IP pública del ordenador que escucha peticiones y "" con el número de puerto que hayamos configurado en el paso 2. Por ejemplo, si la dirección IP pública de tu ordenador es "123.456.789.123" y el puerto es "8080", la URL sería:

   ```
   http://123.456.789.123:8080
   ```

   Al acceder a esa URL desde otro ordenador conectado a internet, se establecerá una conexión con el servidor y se podrá interactuar con él.

He probado esto pero no funciona y no sé muy bien que hacer. El error que obtengo es Conection refused al intentar hacer una petición al servidor.

Comment: Hacer esto va a requerir que implementes de manera obligatoria procesos de seguridad, y de protección en la app. Generalmente exponer así la IP no es recomendable, aún así si tienes la opción de vincular un dominio personalizado, sería algo más viable, puedes hacer esto con un registro _A_ en un proveedor de DNS. Si estás dispuesto a tener un ordenador físico durante todo el día y todos los días, tienes que evaluar la situación. Para abordar esto normalmente se usan servidores VPS o en la nube.

Comment: Eso depende de muchas cosas... también, es probable que, cuando buscas tu IP publica, normalmente es la IP de tu "router", y tu router no tiene el puerto especificado abierto, deberías hacer alguna configuración en tu router para indicarle que si le llega alguna solicitud a ese puerto te la reenvie a tu máquina local.

Comment: Tienes que abrir un puerto en tu router que dirija a la ip (ó mac) de tu pc. Te tienes que conectar a la ip publica que tu proveedor de internet te asigno, que puede ser fija ó dinámica. Si es dinamica, generalmente se adquiere una nueva ip cada vez que reinicias el router y por tanto, tendrás que cambiarla para poder seguir accediendo a tu aplicación. En este caso, lo mejor es contratar un servidor en la nube. Estos siempre tienen ip estatica. Linode es una buena opción y económica.